# Make an excel chart based on a pivot table, with multiple years

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I've had this problem for some time. Using Mac, Excel v15, 2016.

[image: Pivot table, and the chart coming out of it]

As you can see, I have 2015 and 2016 (ignore the months showing as Jan-15, think of them as just month names; I tried editing that by hand to see if it works)

I want the chart to continue into 2016. If I group by year, it doesn't work to turn into Jan-15, and Jan-16... which I think will make the charting easy. 
So how can I do that?

Comment: Thanks @Raystafarian, but can you please elaborate?

Comment: Try double clicking the x-axis and setting the range and interval to what you desire.

Comment: Oh yeah... tried that, but it's including the year in there too. http://imgur.com/9Sp2S95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark - Are you looking for something like this?

[image]

Where the data was set up as follows ...

[image]

Because you can't see it all - the Y Values are, for `Sum of Data2` ...

```
=(myPivot!$B$5:$B$16,myPivot!$B$18:$B$21)
```

... and for `Sum of Data1` ...

```
=(myPivot!$C$5:$C$16,myPivot!$C$18:$C$21)
```

... and for Category labels ...

```
=(myPivot!$A$5:$A$16,myPivot!$A$18:$A$21)
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I needed @OldUgly. Thanks so much for the elaborate answer with screenshots, thanks for taking the time to create that. All that was missing in my knowledge was using a comma and locating the next set of rows, so A5 to A16 and then add a comma and then select A18 to A21.

Comment: Note the brackets as well

Comment: Oh... weird, the brackets didn't give me any trouble (didn't use them) @OldUgly.. maybe it's my version?